# How do I /give a named item?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been trying to use the `/give` command to give a named book, but I can't seem to give it. I keep on getting the error message of:

> Line 1, Column 2 Missing '}' or object member name.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The below command should do it:

```
/give @p minecraft:book 1 0 {display:{Name:"example-name"}}
```